# 'How to setting color of fractal to three roots '

Tags: plotting

I am trying to create the basin of attraction of newtons method, below code is working for fractal but I cannot set fractal colors for three roots,
How to set these colors for three roots. I use the mathematica11 version. please advise.

```
f[z_] := z^3 - 1;
df[z_] := 3*z^2;
 Do[rootf[k] = N[Exp[2*(k - 1)*Pi*I/3]], {k, 1, 3}];
rootPosition = 
  Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, Which[Abs[z - rootf[1]] < 10.0^(-3), 3,
    Abs[z - rootf[2]] < 10.0^(-3), 2,
    Abs[z - rootf[3]] < 10.0^(-3), 1,
    True, 0], {{rootf[_], _Complex}}];
iterNewton = Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, z - f[z]/df[z]];
iterColorAlgorithm[iterMethod_, x_, y_, lim_] := 
  Block[{z, ct, r}, z = x + y I; ct = 0; r = rootPosition[z];
   While[(r == 0) && (ct < lim), ++ct; z = iterMethod[z]; 
    r = rootPosition[z]];
   If[Head[r] == Which, r = 0];
   Return[N[r + ct/(lim + 0.001)]]];
limIterations = 25;
xxMin = -3;
xxMax = 3;
yyMin = -3;
yyMax = 3;
colorLevel = Compile[{{p, _Real}}, 0.4*FractionalPart[4*p]];
fractalColor[p_] := 
  Block[{pp = colorLevel[p]}, Switch[IntegerPart[4*p],
    3, CMYKColor[0.6 + pp, 0., 0., 2*pp],
    2, CMYKColor[0., 0.6 + pp, 0., 2*pp],
    1, CMYKColor[0., 0., 0.6 + pp, 2*pp],
    0, CMYKColor[0., 0., 0., 1.]]];



plotColorFractal[iterMethod_, points_] := 
  DensityPlot[
   iterColorAlgorithm[iterMethod, x, y, limIterations], {x, xxMin, 
    xxMax}, {y, yyMin, yyMax}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}, 
   PlotPoints -> points, Mesh -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> fractalColor];

plotColorFractal[iterNewton, 256]
```

---

I obtained the figure and [image]

But our picture should be the same as following the original picture.[image]

Comment: Could you include the figure you obtain and point out exactly where the problem is, and indicate what you would like to obtain instead?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
f[z_] := z^3 - 1;
newton[f_, z_, z0_] :=
  Block[
   {df = D[f, z], fz0, dfz0},
   fz0 = (f /. z -> z0);
   dfz0 = (df /. z -> z0);
   z0 - fz0/dfz0
   ];
nt = Compile[
   {{z0, _Complex}},
   Evaluate@newton[z^3 - 1, z, z0],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
iterAlgorithm =
   Compile[{{c, _Complex}, {lim, _Integer}, {delta, _Real}}, 
   Module[
    {z1 = c , z2 = nt[c], ctr = 0},
    While[ctr < lim && Abs[z2 - z1] > delta,
     ++ctr;
     z1 = z2;
     z2 = nt[z1];
     ];
    (3*(Arg[z2] + \[Pi] - \[Pi]/3))/(2 \[Pi]) + ctr/lim
    ]
   ,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];
makeFractal[iterAlgorithm_, lim_, delta_, points_, range_] :=

  iterAlgorithm[
   Table[
    x + y I,
    {y, range[[2, 1]], 
     range[[2, 2]], (range[[2, 2]] - range[[2, 1]])/points},
    {x, range[[1, 1]], 
     range[[1, 2]], (range[[1, 2]] - range[[1, 1]])/points}
    ],
   lim,
   delta
   ];

 ArrayPlot[
 Quiet@makeFractal[iterAlgorithm, 25, 0.001, 
   128, {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}],
 PlotRange -> {0, 4},
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (Darker[
     Switch[
      IntegerPart[#],
      0, Yellow,
      1, Blue,
      2, Red
      ], FractionalPart[#]
     ]
    &)
 ]
```

**TIP**

1. CompilationTarget->"C" option boosts compiled function.
2. Instead of precalculating roots, determining which root a point converged to by its Arg.
3. use ArrayPlot and table data instead of DensityPlot because it's slow.

Comment: Hayashi Yoshiaki, Thank you. It works very fast.  But I can’t show axes around the picture. Please advise me regarding how to present the axes of the picture. (x, [-3,3]; y, [-3;3])

Comment: @onk add `Frame->True, FrameTicks->All` in ArrayPlot options. Plz search the documentarion of ArrayPlot or this site for further details.